# Grails 2.2.1 groupProperty on Integration tests

Tags: grails, grails-orm

For some reason the groupProperty is not working on my integration tests. I'm getting the following exception:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   mypackage.CarIntTests.groupProperty() is applicable for argument
>   types: (java.lang.String) values: [car]

```
def names = ['Honda', 'Toyota', 'Nissan']
3.times {
    Garage.build(name: names[it])
}
def results = Garage.withCriteria {
    car {
        eq('brand', 'Honda')
    }
    projections {
        groupProperty('car')
    }
}
assert results == names[0..0]
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question inserting the piece of code that throws the exception?

Comment: For a better help, please post your relevant code. I'm guessing that your integration test is using the `@Mock` annotation, but this is only for unit tests.

Comment: You right. I completely forgot about it, and included the annotation. Thanks a lot!